# Can this drain pipe in an interior soffit be moved up into the floor framing?

Tags: soffit

I found the drain pipe in the soffit when I planning to renovate the kitchen. Can one corner section of the drain pipe move up to the ceiling? Please let me know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help. Please provide much more detail about the circuit in your question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips on how to use this site.

Answer (score 2):

We have no way of knowing whether this pipe can be moved into the ceiling.

That's going to be determined by where it comes from, where it's going, and whether or not the pipe can be raised and still maintain slope for proper drainage.

*However*, the odds are *really* good that the answer is "NO" for a couple of reasons:

1. Nobody puts plumbing in a soffit "just because". *Generally*, people don't want soffits and they're only installed when that's the only option.
2. That looks like 2" or 3" drain pipe which won't fit nicely into a 2x4 wall - the holes necessary to get the pipe through the studs will be too big to safely drill without damaging the studs beyond their ability to support much of anything.

Your best bet would be to call in a local plumber or two for an estimate on getting the drains moved. If they can't be moved, they'll tell you right away. If they can be, you'll know what they'll charge you, and it's then up to you to hire one of them, or DIY it.

Comment: This drain pipe comes from the bathroom on the 2nd floor.

Comment: I generally agree, but if the soffit was there for other reasons it's probably easier to run the drain pipe in it than above.

Comment: Depending on where the drain pipe is coming from and going to, an alternative might be to bring it straight down and join the rest of the drainage system in the basement. That would require venting, though, which may be why this was joined to an existing drain stack instead. In my (1890ish) house they seem to have solved this by raising the floor in the bedroom suite so the drain could reach the chimney core and go down there.

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to the duct hanging down, it is an exhaust duct to connect to a rangehood or kitchen exhaust fan.

The duct itself can be wherever you like.  But the outlet should be on the soffit.

There are two main types of rangehood.

- The first one has the fan in the hood and you can connect the duct to it.
- The other one has the fan in the ceiling space, so you will have to dissect the duct to install the motor and provide power to it.

Before you do anything with the duct

- Trace it to see if there is a fan in the middle of the duct (and remove it)
- Check what the new rangehood configuration is.

Comment: The question mentions drain pipe, not ducting.

Comment: @isherwood, I  know  but not everyone knows the terminology.